# Kubernetes with AWS Elastic Block Storage

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, kubernetes

We are trying to Configure kubernetes RC in AWS instance with AWS Elastic Block Store(EBS). here is the key part of our controller yaml file -

```
      volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: "/opt/phabricator/repo"
          name: ebsvol
  volumes:
    -
      name: ebsvol
      awsElasticBlockStore:
        volumeID: aws://us-west-2a/vol-*****
        fsType: ext4
```

our rc can start pod and works fine with out mounting it to a AWS EBS but with volume mounting in an AWS EBS it gives us -

```
Fri, 11 Sep 2015 11:29:14 +0000 Fri, 11 Sep 2015 11:29:34 +0000 3   {kubelet 172.31.24.103}         failedMount Unable to mount volumes for pod "phabricator-controller-zvg7z_default": error listing AWS instances: NoCredentialProviders: no valid providers in chain
  Fri, 11 Sep 2015 11:29:14 +0000   Fri, 11 Sep 2015 11:29:34 +0000 3   {kubelet 172.31.24.103}         failedSync  Error syncing pod, skipping: error listing AWS instances: NoCredentialProviders: no valid providers in chain
```

We have an credential file with appropiate credential in .aws directory. But its not working.
Do we missing something? Is it a configuration issue?

Kubectl version: 1.0.4 and 1.0.5 (Tried with both)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We opened an issue to discuss this: 
https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/13858

The recommended way to go here is to use IAM instance profiles.  kube-up does configure this for you, and if you're not using kube-up I recommend looking at it to emulate what it does!

Although we did recently merge in support for using a .aws credentials file, I don't believe it has been back-ported into any release, and it isn't really the way I (personally) recommend.

It sounds like you're not using kube-up; you may find it easier if you can use that (and I'd love to know if there's some reason you can't or don't want to use kube-up, as I personally am working on an alternative that I hope will meet everyone's needs!)

I'd also love to know if IAM instance profiles aren't suitable for you for some reason.